# How to Remove Dead Row Version in Postgres 9.2

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2

I ran a vaccum on the tables of my database and it appears it is not helping me. For example I have a huge table and when I run vacuum on it, it returns there are 87887889 dead row versions that can not be deleted

My question is how to get rid of these dead rows

Comment: Do you have any open transactions? Or connections in "<idle in transaction>" state?

Comment: Also, `SHOW max_prepared_transactions;` and `select * from pg_prepared_xacts;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two basic options if a routine vacuum is insufficient.  Both require a full table lock.

1. VACUUM FULL.  This requires no additional disk space but takes a while to complete.
2. CLUSTER.  This rewrites a table in a physical order optimized for a given index.  It requires additional space to do the rewrite, but is much faster.

In general I would recommend using CLUSTER during a maintenance window if disk space allows.